# Python / web scrape / aspx -- is it humanly possible when there are no forms?

Tags: asp.net, python, scrape

Total noob, obviously.  Teaching self Python for web scraping in the interest of open records/government transparency/reporting/etc.

There's an .aspx page I want to scrape, a week-by-week calendar for January - March 2012

But it has no forms ...

Perhaps you fine people can tell me if a solution is even possible before I spend days fighting with it.

http://webmail.legis.ga.gov/Calendar/default.aspx?chamber=house

The only way to see the appointments on the calendar is by choosing a day on a picture of a calendar.  But, at least, if you click on Monday, it shows all the week's appointments.  (I would like to gather all those appointments in order to count how often each committee meets, a bit of a proxy for counting what kind of legislation gets attention and what kind is ignored.)

But so, what strategy to use? It appears that each month at least down in its bowels is assigned to a sequential four-digit number prepended with a "V", like V4414, and days with a non-prepended number.

I'm only hunting Jan - Mar 2012; other months are non-germane and mostly empty.

a clue?

```
    ...<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','V4414')" style="color:#333333" title="Go to the previous month">February</a></td><td align="center" style="width:70%;">March 2012</td><td align="right" valign="bottom" style="color:#333333;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;width:15%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','V4474')" style="color:#333333" title="Go to the next month">April</a></td></tr>
```

a pattern?

```
    ...<td align="center" style="color:#999999;width:14%;"><a      href="javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','4439')" style="color:#999999" title="February 26">26</a></td><td align="center" style="color:#999999;width:14%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','4440')" style="color:#999999" title="February 27">27</a></td><td align="center" style="color:#999999;width:14%;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','4441')" style="color:#999999" title="February 28">28</a></td>...
```

Cheers and thanks!!

Comment: it does have a `form` element.

Answer (score 5):

The form contains four `input`s with `name`s of:

- `__EVENTTARGET`
- `__EVENTARGUMENT`
- `__VIEWSTATE`
- `__EVENTVALIDATION`

The latter two have initial values. You need to scrape those. The former two are set by those links. For example, you have a link:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','4504')" style="color:Black" title="May 01">1</a>
```

Look at the `href`:

```
javascript:__doPostBack('calMain','4504')
```

Somehow, parse those two strings out of it. The former is `__EVENTTARGET`. The latter is `__EVENTARGUMENT`.

Once you have all four pieces of data, you can issue a `POST` request to get the next page.

Comment: Thanks y'all!  I will post a link here when the work is done. I know it will be fascinating, lolz.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* replicate the POST request in Python using something like `urllib.parse.urlencode` to build the query strings.

For this you will have to find out what the query string looks like, obviously. Or, you could use another tool like [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).